# Headless browser or web scraper software with deploy option

Tags: windows, web-scraping, headless-browser

I need to make simple, stand-alone scraper utility for end-users. I wanted to use PhantomJS but I can't find a way to hide script from end-users; I need to do this because the script is used to control a third-party website using the user's own access credentials. Is there any other web scraper or headless browser I can deploy in single Windows executable file or with script secured from users? Or is there a way in PhantomJS?

I thought about downloading script for PhantomJS when program is starting, but there should be better way to do this.

Preferred language is JavaScript, but can be any other if necessary.

Comment: This is rather too broad for Stack Overflow, especially given the minimal detail. What operating system do you want this to run on? Why do you want to hide the scrape script from end users (your answer here may affect the answers given). Could you offer this as a web site that does the scraping on behalf of users, rather than requiring them to download and run something?

Comment: End-users use windows systems. Can't offer it as website, as this script is used by end-users to manipulate they own accounts on other website. (It fills surveys based on given key). Script needs to be hidden from end-users, cause they tend to distribute them later for free without my knowledge.

Comment: OK. Does compiling this as an executable binary protect against users distributing them for free? They could just as easily give them away, I would guess.

Comment: You re absolutely right, and i have two options possible: Either do some server based identification(which i planned) or hope that website they use and i don't own will change something that will require changes in script. Both options require script protection from end-user to work... Im not golddigger, but i hate when i sell ten scripts and later i see about hundred in use sold by someone else.